# When changing the attribute of a folder, how do I apply to all the folders and files under the folder?

Tags: perl, attributes, directory

I use [`Win32::File`](http://p3rl.org/Win32%3a%3aFile) to change the attribute of a folder, but only the the attribute of the folder changed, the the folders and files under the folder didn't change.

When I use Win32::File to change just the attribute of a file, the return value is 1 which means it works successfully, but still I can't write-open it. `open (FILE, ">", "$somepath")` failed.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [File::Find](http://p3rl.org/File%3a%3aFind) to traverse the directory structure, changing the attributes on every hit.